# How did this code work

Tags: c, arrays, char, return

```
char *My_Time(FILE *prnt) 
{
  time_t raw_Time = time(0);
  struct tm *info;
  char myt_Time[80];

  info = localtime(&raw_Time);
  return asctime(info);// Returns the time i want 
}

int Crte_acclg (FILE *crte_Fp1)
{
  char *my_Currtime;
  my_Currtime = My_Time(crte_Fp1);    // succesfully stores the time i want without having a array of chars?
  fprintf(crte_Fp1,"File Created: %s",my_Currtime);
  return 1;
}
```

So in the above code I ask my time to return the current time , and I store it in a char *. My question is how did this line of code work , because i am taking back a string of chars so why when I point to a Char position it is able to give me the complete string?

Comment: An string is an array of chars that ends with `\0`. In C++ there is also an `string` class.

Comment: What you get is a pointer to the first char of the string. When you print a string the function iterate on this string until `\0` is found.

Comment: Are you saying that the `fprintf` call in `Crte_acclg` doesn't output the complete time/date string? How do you know, how do you check? If you check the file while the program is running, it might be that the output haven't been flushed to the actual file yet.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg no he confuses between `char` and `char*`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it does but because asctime ( info) is a string of characters does the compiler line up the data in memory so passing the * to the end of the char , can allow me to read all the chars stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many types of strings, and the standard C string is a sequence with sentinel value 0.

The `char*` returned points to this sequence, which is equivalent to pointing to its first element.

`asctime()` can return this pointer safely, because it uses an internal static buffer which is large enough, and you promised by using it never to use it concurrently, nor to depend on the returned value after calling another standard function allowed to use this buffer.

Aside: Best get the standard [C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (link copied from wikipedia).

Answer (score 0):

A string is nothing more than a sequence of characters somewhere in memory. When you have a pointer to the string, it points to the first character in the string.

Lets say we have a string like this:

```
char someString[] = "Hello world";
```

In memory it looks like this:

```
+-----------------+
| "Hello world\0" |
+-----------------+
```

Now when you have a pointer pointing to this string

```
char *pointerToString = someString;
```

it will be like

```
+-----------------+     +-----------------+
| pointerToString | --> | "Hello world\0" |
+-----------------+     +-----------------+
```

---

The `asctime` function have an array similar to `someString` in my example above. That array is declared to be `static` which means it will not go out of scope once the function returns. As arrays decays to pointers, that means that when the `asctime` returns the array, it will turn into a pointer to the first character in that array, and it's that pointer you get to see and use.